# Why is the auxiliary field from Hubbard-Stratonovich transformation for Hubbard model the same as the mean-field ferromagnetic order parameter?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, path-integral

This question comes from the Fradkin's *Field Theory of Condensed Matter Physics*, P50 (3.122),
$$ M = \sqrt{\dfrac{4U}{3}} \phi $$
where $M$ is the ferromagnetic order parameter and $\phi$ is the auxiliary field from the Hubbard-Stratonovich transformation. The book argues that because the above equation is correct, the mean field theory which is derived from the Hartree-Fock approach is equivalent to the the saddle point approximation formalism for H-S transformation auxiliary field Lagrangian. But I can not understand the equation.

Comment: related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/79183/hubbard-stratonovich-transformation-and-mean-field-approximation

Answer (score 3):

You can always derive connection between auxiliary fields in saddle point and averages of fermion operators they are coupled to. For example, take a full decoupled action:
\begin{equation}
S=\frac{1}{2m}\sum\phi(q)\phi(-q)+g\sum\phi(q)M(-q)+S_f,
\end{equation}
where $\phi$ is an auxiliary field, $S_f$ denotes fermonic part of action and $M(-q)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k\alpha\beta}\bar{\psi}_\alpha(k-q)\psi_\beta(k)\tau^z_{\alpha\beta}$ is just a FT of spin in z direction. 
Now, consider a variational derivative with respect to $\phi_q$ in a saddle point (where $\frac{\delta}{\delta \phi_q} S=0$ holds):

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{Z}\frac{\delta }{\delta \phi_q}Z
=
\frac{1}{m}\phi_{MF}(-q)+g\left<M(-q)\right>_{MF}
=
-\frac{1}{Z}\int D(\bar{\psi}, \psi)e^{-S}\frac{\delta }{\delta \phi_q}S
=
0
\end{equation}
Which means that:
\begin{equation}
-\frac{1}{gm}\phi(q)
=
\left<M(q)\right>.
\end{equation}

I hope it answers your question.